# Load File TxT Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, readfile

How can I load in a matrix A a txt file which has this content:

```
n
a11 a12
a21 a22
a31 a32
.......
an1 an2
```

n - number of lines and it's an int and a11...an2 are float types

Let's say for n = 3 I would have something like this:

```
3
1.5 1.8
84.21 15.2
41.5 2.0
```

Threfore my matrix A would be : `[1.5 1.8; 84.21 15.2; 41.5 2.0]`

Comment: `A = textread("file", "headerlines", 1);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the following ways:

1. `A = textread('a.txt', '', 'headerlines', 1);`
2. `A = dlmread('a.txt', ' ', 1)`